# split characters into two variables in data frame

Tags: r, reshape2

Let's say I have a vector of variables like this:

```
>variable
[1] "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A2" "A2" "A2" "A2" "B1" "B1" "B1" "B1"
```

and I want to covert this into into a data frame like this:

```
  treatment time
1         A    1
2         A    1
3         A    1
4         A    1
5         A    2
6         A    2
7         A    2
8         A    2
9         B    1
10        B    1
11        B    1
12        B    1
```

To that end, I used reshape2's colsplit function. It rquires a pattern to split the string, but I quickly realize there is no obvious pattern to split the two characters without any space.
I tried "" and got the following results:

```
> colsplit(trialm$variable,"",names=c("treatment","time"))
   treatment time
1         NA   A1
2         NA   A1
3         NA   A1
4         NA   A1
5         NA   A2
6         NA   A2
7         NA   A2
8         NA   A2
9         NA   B1
10        NA   B1
11        NA   B1
12        NA   B1
```

I also tried a lookbehind or lookahead regular expression :

```
>colsplit(trialm$variable,"(?<=\\w)",names=c("treatment","time"))
Error in gregexpr("(?<=\\w)", c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2",  : 
  invalid regular expression '(?<=\w)', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

but it gave me the above error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: take a look at `strsplit`. Your code will be something like: `trialm$treatment <- sapply(strsplit(trialm$variable,  ''), '[', 1)`

Comment: I know this is OLD, but the `str_split_fixed` that is used by the `colsplit` function is now written differently, and so the code works as you would have expected it to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`substr` is another way to do it.

```
> variable <- c(rep("A1", 4), rep("A2", 4), rep("B1", 4))
> data.frame(treatment=substr(variable, 1,1), time=as.numeric(substr(variable,2,2)))
   treatmen time
1         A    1
2         A    1
3         A    1
4         A    1
5         A    2
6         A    2
7         A    2
8         A    2
9         B    1
10        B    1
11        B    1
12        B    1
```

Comment: ha! +1 if you think best I'll remove it though.

Comment: But what if some of the variables were, say, "AA1", and "A12"? This method won't succeed with those.

Comment: Ananda, you could use regular expressions in your example to separate letters from numbers in tow columns, then see how many discrete categories you have using those two columns.

Comment: two columns, not 'tow' columns

Answer (score 11):

### Update: 24 December 2017

Somewhere along the line, the "stringr" package (which is imported with "reshape2" and which is responsible for the splitting that takes place with `colsplit`) started to use "stringi" for several of its functions. Some behavior seems to have changed because of that.

Using the current "reshape2" (and current "stringr" package), `colsplit` works the way you would have expected it to with your code:

```
packageVersion("reshape2")
## [1] ‘1.4.3’
packageVersion("stringr")
## [1] ‘1.2.0’

colsplit(variable, "", names = c("treatment", "time"))
##    treatment time
## 1          A    1
## 2          A    1
## 3          A    1
## 4          A    1
## 5          A    2
## 6          A    2
## 7          A    2
## 8          A    2
## 9          B    1
## 10         B    1
## 11         B    1
## 12         B    1
```

### Original Answer: 24 April 2013

If a pattern can be detected in your "variable" but there is no clean split character that can be used, then add one :)

```
library(reshape2)
variable <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", 
              "A2", "A2", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1")
## Here, we add a "." between upper case letters and numbers
colsplit(gsub("([A-Z])([0-9])", "\\1\\.\\2", variable), 
         "\\.", c("Treatment", "Time"))
#    Treatment Time
# 1          A    1
# 2          A    1
# 3          A    1
# 4          A    1
# 5          A    2
# ::::: snip :::: #
# 11         B    1
# 12         B    1
```

---

### Additional Options: 23 December 2017

My "splitstackshape" package has a single-purpose non-exported helper function called `NoSep` that can be used for this:

```
splitstackshape:::NoSep(variable)
##    .var .time_1
## 1     A       1
## 2     A       1
## 3     A       1
## 4     A       1
## 5     A       2
## ::: snip :::: #
## 11    B       1
## 12    B       1
```

---

The "tidyverse" (specifically the "tidyr" package) has a couple of convenient functions for splitting values into different columns: `separate` and `extract`. `separate` has [already been demonstrated by jazzuro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28314421/1270695), but the solution is very specific to this particular problem. Also, it generally works better with a delimiter. `extract` expects you to specify a regular expression with the groups you want to capture:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(variable) %>% 
  extract(variable, into = c("Treatment", "Time"), regex = "([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
#    Treatment Time
# 1          A    1
# 2          A    1
# 3          A    1
# 4          A    1
# 5          A    2
# ::::: snip :::: #
# 11         B    1
# 12         B    1
```

Answer (score 7):

If you create a data frame with the vector, `variable`, you could use `separate()` from the `tidyr` package now.

```
mydf <- data.frame(variable = c(rep("A1", 4), rep("A2", 4), rep("B1", 4)),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

separate(mydf, variable, c("treatement", "time"), sep = 1)

#   treatement time
#1           A    1
#2           A    1
#3           A    1
#4           A    1
#5           A    2
#6           A    2
#7           A    2
#8           A    2
#9           B    1
#10          B    1
#11          B    1
#12          B    1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `substr` to split it:

e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(treatment =   substr(variable, start = 1, stop = 1),
                 time =        substr(variable, start = 2, stop = 2) )
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using regular expression

```
require(stringr)
variable <- c(paste0("A", c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 3))),
              paste0("B", rep(1, 4))
              )

data.frame(
    treatment = str_extract(variable, "[[:alpha:]]"),
    time = as.numeric(str_extract(variable, "[[:digit:]]"))
    )

##    treatment time
## 1          A    1
## 2          A    1
## 3          A    1
## 4          A    1
## 5          A    2
## 6          A    2
## 7          A    2
## 8          B    1
## 9          B    1
## 10         B    1
## 11         B    1
```

Comment: +1. I think this is the *safer* than `substr` and so on if a pattern is discernible but no splitting character is available.

Answer (score 4):

A new function `tstrsplit()` was introduced in `data.table v1.9.5`. The `t` stands for *transpose*. It's the result of splitting a character vector with  `strsplit()` and then *transposing* it.

```
# dummy data
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(var = c(rep("A1", 4), rep("A2", 4), rep("B1", 4)))
```

Using `tstrsplit()`:

```
dt[, tstrsplit(var, "")]

    V1 V2
 1:  A  1
 2:  A  1
 3:  A  1
 4:  A  1
 5:  A  2
 6:  A  2
 7:  A  2
 8:  A  2
 9:  B  1
10:  B  1
11:  B  1
12:  B  1
```

Yes, it's that easy. :-)

Comment: That is new! This is the function I will write down in my notebook today.

Answer (score 3):

You can use substring() to create vectors then join them using the data.frame function.

```
yyy<-c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1")

treatment<-substring(yyy, 1,1)

time<-as.numeric(substring(yyy,2,2))

data.frame(treatment,time)
```

Comment: +1 for realizing that `time` is a `factor` and you want it to be `numeric` using `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `strsplit`

```
df <- t(data.frame(strsplit(variable, "")))
rownames(df) <- NULL
colnames(df) <- c("treatment" , "time" )
df
      treatment time
 [1,] "A"       "1" 
 [2,] "A"       "1" 
 [3,] "A"       "1" 
 [4,] "A"       "1" 
 [5,] "A"       "2" 
 [6,] "A"       "2" 
 [7,] "A"       "2" 
 [8,] "A"       "2" 
 [9,] "B"       "1" 
[10,] "B"       "1" 
[11,] "B"       "1" 
[12,] "B"       "1"
```

---

Instead of using `t` you can use `rbind` and then coerce to `data.frame` as follows:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(variable, ""))), 
         c("Treatment", "Time"))
#    Treatment Time
# 1          A    1
# 2          A    1
# 3          A    1
# 4          A    1
# 5          A    2
# 6          A    2
# 7          A    2
# 8          B    1
# 9          B    1
# 10         B    1
# 11         B    1
```

Comment: Perhaps sufficient for the OP's needs, but what if some of the variables were, say, "AA1", and "A12"? This method won't succeed with those.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of @Justin I suggest this (using `v <- c("A1", "B2")`):

```
> t(sapply(strsplit(v, ''), '[', c(1, 2)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "1" 
[2,] "B"  "2"
```

The vector after `'[' selects the items from the split vector.  So I split only once, keeping both items.  Maybe this is even easier if you want to keep every item:

```
t(sapply(strsplit(v, ''), identity))
```